# How to auto checked of checkbox from a value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a some checkbox with each value .I want to auto checked of checkbox . I use logic & in this case , but it's not working.
Example : value sum = 5 : food and water is checked , sum = 4 : water is checked, sum = 3 : candy and food is checked , ....

```js
var sum = 5;
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox1");
for (var i = 0; list[i]; ++i) 
{
if (  (sum & list[i].val()) == list[i].val() ) 
{
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
}
}
```

```html
<table id="div_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="candy" value="2" />
            </td>
            <td>Candy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="food" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td>Food</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="water" value="4" />
            </td>
            <td>Water</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank  guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current checkbox dom object lies in `list[i]` in for loop. you can convert the object to jquery and then set property checked to true:

```
for (var i = 0; list[i]; ++i){
 var currentchckbox = $(list[i]);
  if ((sum & currentchckbox.val()) == currentchckbox .val() ) {
    currentchckbox.prop('checked', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: ,Seem it's not working ,  Uncaught TypeError: list[i].val is not a function

Comment: @BrianCrist, use `$(list[i])`

Comment: It's log console error at 'if (  (sum & list[i].val()) == list[i].val() )'

Comment: @BrianCrist: you would also need to convert that element dom object into jquery object to use `.val()` along with it.